# Proving if the functor $R[X]\otimes_R\square$ is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Im trying to prove whether the $Functor$: $R[X]\otimes_R\square: Mod_R \to Mod_R$ is an $Exact \space Functor$, i dont know anything about the ring $R$.
( If i understand right, this is equivalent to show that the module $R[X]$ (over $R$) is $flat$.)

If this $Functor$ is indeed exact,
My attempt was to show that this functor preserves injective maps, and this is the point where I need some help:

Let's say I have the injective map $i:M \to N$ between two left $R-Modules$.

So, the induced map would be $i*:R[X]\otimes_R M \to R[X]\otimes_R N$. To show this map is injective, let $r[x]\otimes_Rm \in ker(i*)$. How can I use $i$ injectiveness to show that the element $r[x]\otimes_Rm$ is zero ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you know about Tor groups, Tor commutes with direct sums and $R[x]$ is free as an $R$ module, so $Tor(R[x],-)=0$ always, and hence it's flat.

Comment: You don't need any Tor formalism to prove that free modules are flat. This is elementary.

Comment: ah right, whoops

Comment: Does R[X] is free even if R is not commutative ring? cause in my case, R is a general ring, not necessarily commutative.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice. I haven't done too much with noncommutative rings, so what I say may be wrong, but I think it should still be free as a right R module generated by x^n, and I think the tensor product is the same as Z[x]\otimes M where the tensor product is taken over Z and M is considered a Z module (the R linearity allows you to move over all R coefficients on the left). I think this should imply exactness?